# "x" is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008, protractor

I'm trying to get a result from Sql query.
I have the following class which should execute the Sql connection and query:

```js
'use strict';

 //db.js
const sql = require('mssql');
require('dotenv').config();

var utils = function(){

var config = {
  server: 'sql01',
  database: 'db123',
  options: {
   instanceName: 'in1',
   encrypt: true
  }
};

module.exports = {

/** Define sql queries here  */
  GetEmpName(id) {
    let my_query = `Select filed1 FROM db123 WHERE id='${id}'`;
    sql.connect(config).then(function () {
      new sql.Request()
        .query(my_query).then(function (recordset) {}).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
};
};
```

And that's the main page:

```js
'use strict;'
 let HomePage = require('../page/home_page.js');
 let utilsPage = require('../utils/utils.js');
describe("login to website",function(){
     let employeeId;
     let employeeBday;
     let home = new HomePage();
     //let utils = new utilsPage();
      
    it('get an employee's Id', function (done) {
       utilsPage.GetEmpName('100001387');
       done();
    })
});
```

I'm getting an error says: `utilsPage is not a constructor`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Node.js there are two ways of exporting and accessing function variables. One is by creating a global function and putting all your functions, variables into that and export that module as a whole by using `module.exports`.

Another way is just exporting the function by `exports` and then accessing that in your specific file. So in your case you could do it in either of the below 2 ways-

**1st Approach:**  Using your `Utils` function globally -

```
'use strict';

 //db.js
const sql = require('mssql');
require('dotenv').config();

var utils = function(){

this.config = {
  server: 'sql01',
  database: 'db123',
  options: {
   instanceName: 'in1',
   encrypt: true
  }
};


/** Define sql queries here  */
  this.getEmpName = function(id) {
    let my_query = `Select filed1 FROM db123 WHERE id='${id}'`;
    sql.connect(config).then(function () {
      new sql.Request()
        .query(my_query).then(function (recordset) {}).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
};

module.exports = new utils();
```

You could use it the same way as you have used -

```
 'use strict;'
 let HomePage = require('../page/home_page.js');
 let utilsPage = require('../utils/utils.js');
describe("login to website",function(){
     let employeeId;
     let employeeBday;
     let home = new HomePage();

    it('get an employee's Id', function (done) {
       utilsPage.getEmpName('100001387');
       done();
    })
});
```

**2nd Approach:** Exporting only the `getEmpName` function -

```
'use strict';

 //db.js
const sql = require('mssql');
require('dotenv').config();


var config = {
  server: 'sql01',
  database: 'db123',
  options: {
   instanceName: 'in1',
   encrypt: true
  }
};


/** Define sql queries here  */
  exports.getEmpName = function(id) {
    let my_query = `Select filed1 FROM db123 WHERE id='${id}'`;
    sql.connect(config).then(function () {
      new sql.Request()
        .query(my_query).then(function (recordset) {}).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

You would use it the same as well:

```
'use strict;'
     let HomePage = require('../page/home_page.js');
     let utilsPage = require('../utils/utils.js');
    describe("login to website",function(){
         let employeeId;
         let employeeBday;
         let home = new HomePage();

        it('get an employee's Id', function (done) {
           utilsPage.getEmpName('100001387');
           done();
        })
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In your `utils.js` file you shouldn't wrap your code in the `utils` function

```
'use strict';

//db.js
const sql = require('mssql');
require('dotenv').config();

var config = {
    server: 'sql01',
    database: 'db123',
    options: {
        instanceName: 'in1',
        encrypt: true
    }
};

module.exports = {
    /** Define sql queries here  */
    GetEmpName(id) {
        let my_query = `Select filed1 FROM db123 WHERE id='${id}'`;
        sql.connect(config).then(function () {
            new sql.Request()
                .query(my_query).then(function (recordset) { }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        });
    }
};
```

In your main page file you can access your exported module like this

```
utilsPage.GetEmpName('100001387')
```

There's no need to call `new utilsPage()`. In order to use the keyword `new` you must either export a `class` or a constructor function.

Comment: May be you forgot to remove this first `let utils = new utilsPage();`

Comment: It should give another error now right? Something like `utils is not defined`. Try replacing `utils.GetEmpName('100001387');` with `utilsPage.GetEmpName('100001387');` in your main page.

Comment: did it(as you can see I upadted my post), but still the same error

Comment: Oh... If the error stays the same no matter how you change it, may be the bundle is not rebuilt correctly. Could you try adding a `console.log` to see if the code is updated.

Comment: where do I need to add the `console.log`?

Comment: Anywhere in your main page. Maybe after the requires.

Comment: looks like it fails just after the `let utilsPage = require('../utils/utils.js');`

Comment: Ah I see. In your `utils.js` file, you don't need to wrap everything in a `utils` function. Because `module.exports` is nested inside that function, it'd never get called, so we get the error.

Comment: I think I understand but I got lost. can you edit your answer please according to your suggestion and how should I implement it? I have tried to change it but still getting the same error